# Talend - Modification of Java Code

Tags: talend

I'm wondering how I can edit the Java code on the Code tab of the job.  I've been trying to look everywhere but can't find it.  I've been wanting to add more codes into it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot edit the generated code in this tab, but you can:

- add some custom code using [tJava](https://help.talend.com/search/all?query=tJava), [tJavaFlex](https://help.talend.com/search/all?query=tJavaFlex) or [tJavaRow](https://help.talend.com/search/all?query=tJavaRow)
- develop your own .jar and include it using [tLibraryLoad](https://help.talend.com/search/all?query=tLibraryLoad)
- develop [your own Talend component](https://help.talend.com/reader/QDC7DnW3S_chYXXornFuGw/3QRqVgh0vXKx3BPeUidHZw)
- build the job and edit the exported Java sources, but at this point better not use Talend and develop directly in Java.

Comment: About the fourth bullet point, if developed entirely in java post export, how to build it for new jar?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use Talend. Their Open Studio product is a bait and switch, their product is cumbersome to use, and source code control is impossible without paying for the full product.